# Writing directly to socket vs to buffer

Tags: go, tcp, network-programming

I have seen **multiple applications** write their data **first to buffer, then writing that buffer to socket** and not just **directly to socket**.

I have two questions:

- **Why is that?**
- If writing straight to socket is reasonable, then: How can I make socket **wait for more data** (We are dealing here with microseconds/nanoseconds delay) or how can I **explicitly tell socket to** **send (not write to internal buffer) data**. Right now kernel is sending each byte I write in seperate packet which is obviously not optimal ;)

I'm making my app in **Go**, here **net.Conn** implements **io.Writer** and it just makes sense to create utility functions that take **2 arguments**: **writer itself** and **data being written**, so at the end I can just type that and be happy:

```golang
packets.WriteUint8(conn, 0x0)
```

I know that in many languages Buffers have their own utility methods for writing/reading structures, but what if I wanted to try above approach specifically in Go? I've tried finding similar questions, but failed.
Info: App is meant to run on Linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applications buffer writes to a network connection because a single write call with a large buffer is more efficient than multiple write calls with small buffers.

Call [SetNoDelay](https://pkg.go.dev/net#TCPConn.SetNoDelay)(false) to make the operating system delay packet transmission with the hope of reducing the number of packets.

There is no option to explicitly flush a TCP connection’s buffer.

Before writing your own utilities, take a look at the [bufio.Writer](https://godoc.org/bufio#Writer) type. Many applications use this type to buffer writes to TCP connections and files.

Comment: This absolutely makes sense, I didn't really want to set NoDelay flag, because I don't trust Nagle algorithm, it failed my expectations many times. I didn't know about bufio.Writer tho and I gotta say, **I love it** for simplicity! One small question, how would my approach perform with actually reading socket? Once I read len of packet, should I just buffer read `len` bytes from connection or reading directly from sockets is alright?

Comment: @Londek Consider using a bufio.Reader to buffer input from a connection.